# windows phone 8.1 RT error with files creation

Tags: c#, windows-phone

in according to this tutorial:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I've written the following function:

```
private async void WriteToFile()
{
   StorageFolder folder =
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   StorageFile sampleFile =
   await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

But, if I run it, I see the following error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event TaskScheduled.
```

Why? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its giving error like 
"Additional information: Use of undefined keyword value 1 for event TaskScheduled"
So may be sample.txt can't able to define as its undefined keyword.

Change file name to other name or "sample1.txt", it will work.

```
private async void WriteToFile()
{
   StorageFolder folder =
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
   StorageFile sampleFile =
   await folder.CreateFileAsync("sample1.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
}
```

Comment: Yes have checked with it, its working with any name other than "sample.txt"

Comment: INCREDIBLE, it's work. The problem was the name. Never seen it before a similar dependencies from the name. You are a wizard!
EDIT: Sorry, I haven't some reputation to vote you.

Comment: But... It works perfectly if I call it from onnavigateto... And doesn't work if I call from i.e. a button. Why? Thank! (Anywhere, the post is solved)